# floating a list to the left

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to find out why does the last element of this list is not being align as the other elements ...

Here's an image so you can appreciate better what I'm talking about:
https://www.screencast.com/t/bIKnShUQhmT1

Here's the webpage:
http://multimueblesrd.com/categoria-producto/muebles/

Thank you!

Comment: You are probably adding `clear` somewhere.

Comment: CSS on your site seems to be not loading sorry

Comment: Add  the image to the question, and add the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not clearing the row before - you need something like this (below) depending on break points, this would clear every 3rd item so when the heights are different they won't wrap - alternative is to force all the heights to be the same.

.products-loop > li:nth-child(2n+1) { clear: both; }

Comment: Forcing uniform heights may also be easier on the eye, but if that's not feasible (you need those titles to wrap), this is the cleanest solution

Answer (score 0):

There is no css problem with your ul list. I think you have your problem on mobile devices. So you need to disable pagination first. If the issue is not resolved try removing 
    `<div class="btt">
    <div id="furnicom-totop">
    <a class="furnicom-totop" href="#" ></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>`
You have to find why the problem is being. Not bcs of your css code. I think there is a proble bcs of your js codes of pagination or because of to top button.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this option out.